# How to have screen height background image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to have a responsive screen height background image as shown in this site http://www.flavorplate.com/. I did research on google and github on that technique but wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any code to share? Try setting `position:fixed` and `height:100%` or `height:auto` in CSS.

Comment: Try looking at the page source. The site only has one stylesheet linked.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do something like this:

```
<div class="bg-image">
      <!-- Featured Content absolute -->
</div> 


<div class="content-wrap">
     <!-- More Content -->
</div>
```

```
html { 
height:100%;
}

body {
height: 100%; 
}

.bg-image {
background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

height: 100%; 
}


.content-wrap {
heigth: auto; 
min-height: 600px; 

}
```

For conditional loading of background-images, you have to use media queries or/and javascript  or a plugin like this: https://github.com/M6Web/picturefill-background

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's incredibly easy, try this:

```
background: url(../IMAGES/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

/* For mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
/* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
 * to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
    background: url(images/background-photo-mobile-devices.jpg);
  }
}
```

You want some more comprehensive Ideas?!! check this out;

[Background Full](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)